# Print word file using pdf printer in excel project

Tags: vba, excel, pdf, ms-word

I am using an excel vba project to create an word file then saving it to pdf using following code.

```
wordapp.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 "" & folder & "" & pdfname & ".pdf", 17
```

I want to print the same word file using PDF printer at path of

```
& folder &
```

and filename as

& pdfname &

I have tried using this as a macro in word file but it asks for a path and filename. Does not automate it.

Comment: what is the exact value of `folder` and `pdfname` during runtime? I guess your path is just wrong or doesn't exist!

Comment: dump your folder and pdfname and make sure they're properly formatted with backslashes

Comment: They are properly formatted. No problem with that. I want to print it as PDF because usual "save as pdf" results in bigger pdf size. But print to pdf results almost half the size.

Comment: I tried this code. wordapp.ActiveDocument.PrintOut PrintToFile:=True, _ OutputFilename:=sItem & pdfname & "_temp" & ".pdf" It converts the word document to pdf. But i cant open the PDF document it says its not a pdf or corrupted. This happens only when i keep hp laserjet printer a a default printer. When i switch default printre to foxit printer then it asks me to give path for pdf file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Code can be used to make Foxit PDF Printer run for your code.

**MAIN CODE**

```
ActivePrinter = "Foxit Reader PDF Printer"
printoutcommand = "wordapp.ActiveDocument.PrintOut
Range:=wdPrintAllDocument, PrintToFile:=True,OutputFilename:=" & sItem &
pdfname & "_temp" & ".pdf"
wordapp.Application.Run "FoxitPrint2PDF"
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
Name "C:\Users\shena\Documents\Document1.pdf" As pdfname & "_temp" & ".pdf"
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
FileCopy "C:\Users\shena\Documents\" & pdfname & "_temp" & ".pdf", sItem & "" & pdfname & "_temp" & ".pdf"
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
Kill "C:\Users\shena\Documents\" & pdfname & "_temp" & ".pdf"
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
wordapp.activedocument.Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
wordapp.Quit
Set wordapp = Nothing
```

**FoxitPrint2PDF** is macro used to set Foxit PDF Printer as default printer and then reset it. Code is as follows

```
Dim sCurrentPrinter As String
On Cancel GoTo Cancelled:
sCurrentPrinter = ActivePrinter
ActivePrinter = "Foxit Reader PDF Printer"
Application.PrintOut FileName:=""
Cancelled:
ActivePrinter = sCurrentPrinter
```

Its just an idea given same code can be written in a module where print operation is going on.
In main code some cut paste operations are seen. Here is the explanation of the same. When we select PDF as a printer we have selected a default location for converted PDF. from that location we are taking it to our desired location. You can see those option at right click on **"Foxit Reader PDF Printer"** then click on **Printing Preferences**. Screen shot of the same is given below for reference.

[image: Printing Preferences Foxit Reader PDF Printer]

Highlighted options are important for us.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the easiest way is to use the `pdfName` as a string and to put a `\` sign before it and the folder.

Try to run this code from Excel file, just make sure that the Excel file is saved successfully, otherwise `ThisWorkbook.Path` would be equl to empty string and you will be asked to save the file during runtime -> `If ThisWorkbook.Path = vbNullString Then ThisWorkbook.Save`

```
Public Sub TetMe()

    Dim wordApp As Object
    Dim WordDoc As Object

    Dim folder  As String
    Dim pdfName As String: pdfName = "someName"

    If ThisWorkbook.Path = vbNullString Then ThisWorkbook.Save        
    Set wordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set WordDoc = wordApp.documents.Add

    folder = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
    wordApp.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 folder & pdfName & ".pdf", 17

End Sub
```

If you are wondering what `17` after `.SaveAs2` is, it is `wdSaveFormat Enumeration` for `wdFormatPDF`.

[WdSaveFormat Enumeration MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/wdsaveformat-enumeration-word)

Comment: Hello @Vityata

I have already developed what you have given in your comment. I have foxit pdf installed and i want to use that as a PDF Printer and convert word file to PDF.
I have tried macro but its not working as i want. Following is the macro code.

Comment: ActivePrinter = "Foxit Reader PDF Printer" wordapp.ActiveDocument.PrintOut Filename:="" & sItem & "" & pdfname & "_temp", Range:=wdPrintAllDocument, Item:= _ wdPrintDocumentWithMarkup, Copies:=1, Pages:="", PageType:= _ wdPrintAllPages, Collate:=True, Background:=True, PrintToFile:=False, _
PrintZoomColumn:=0, PrintZoomRow:=0, PrintZoomPaperWidth:=0, _PrintZoomPaperHeight:=0

This code is not helping me to achive what i want.

Comment: @ShekharNalawade - have you tried the code from the answer? If you have "foxit pdf" this changes the question quite a bit, it is a good idea to ask a new one.

Comment: I have already mentioned the same in question. You are requested to read it carefully.